# Is there a way to pass entire scope to a function

Tags: php

Before going into the details of this question, I'd like to point out that I have never seen this done before, and would be rather curious to see if it can actually be done, and if so, how to go about doing it.

I'm currently sitting on a template loader, and to write it, I have chosen to slightly adapt the HAML file format and extend it with a couple of logic operators - loops, mostly. To do so efficiently, I'd need to pass a list of parameters to the template parser...and I'd prefer to avoid this if possible. While brainstorming for alternatives, the idea came around that maybe, just maybe, it would be possible to reference the scope in which the function was called.

Currently, I'm calling the template parser for a file as follows. Suppose `test()` is a route.

```
function test() {
   $q = $UserModel->tether($userID)->fetchPermissions();
   Util::Templating()->parse("file.haml");
}
```

What I'm trying to avoid is being able to access $q without passing a massively long array as second parameter. My original thought was that there might be a way for `parse()` to inherit the scope in which it was originally called (here, inside `test`) rather than having its own. Is there a way to manage this, and if so, how efficient is it?

Comment: Sounds like a very bad idea. Might be something in http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php. But it'll be very slow.

Comment: @E_p: that's exactly what I'm trying to gauge: the efficiency of a method like this. If it is anything more than 5-10% of the array version, it's a no-go. Convenience is convenience, after all.

Comment: I'm unsure as to how it'd fit in Reflection, though. I think the core of the problem is how to reference the caller scope from the callee, or the caller from the callee - as I honestly know no way to reliable and unambiguously do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Includes the superglobals as well:

```
$a = 'Hello World';
$b = range('A','Z');

$scopeVars = get_defined_vars();

var_dump($scopeVars);
test($scopeVars);


function test($scopeVars) {
    extract($scopeVars);

    echo '$a = '; var_dump($a);
    echo '$b = '; var_dump($b);
}
```

**EDIT**

Just as an experiment, to eliminate the superglobals:

```
$a = 'Hello World';
$b = range('A','Z');

$scopeVars = get_user_defined_vars(get_defined_vars());

test($scopeVars);


function test($scopeVars) {
    extract($scopeVars);

    echo '$a = '; var_dump($a);
    echo '$b = '; var_dump($b);
}

function get_user_defined_vars($vars) {
    return array_diff_key(
        $vars, 
        array_flip(
            array('_SERVER','_GET', '_POST', '_REQUEST', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_ENV')
        )
    );
}
```

But removing the superglobals does seem to make it a bit slower

Comment: I have learned something today. While this is not exactly what I was looking for, I think this is as close to an answer as this question will get.

Answer (score 1):

So i think creating a view object setting it properties and than passing it could work. Or instead of object work with array directly. e.g:

```
function test() {
    $params = array();
    $params['var_1'] = 'qwe1';
    $params['var_2'] = 'qwe2';
    $params['var_3'] = 'qwe3';
    $params['var_4'] = 'qwe4';
    $params['q'] = $UserModel->tether($userID)->fetchPermissions();
    Util::Templating()->parse("file.haml", $params);
}
```

Comment: This is on the table as one of the possible solutions. I was just wondering whether there was a way to do away with the parameter altogether, essentially.

Comment: Why would you do this? Usage of extra memory for nothing. Plus will create more issues than solve.

Comment: The answer is: user convenience. The templating engine in question is aimed at people who have little to no clue. I'm trying to see if it is possible to remove as many of the landmines as possible. (Also, I wasn't thinking of passing by value.)